# Spring Boot Spring Security j_spring_security_check POST Not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

Here's my html/thymeleaf template.

```
<form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4 class="title">Login Access</h4>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="foot">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

My Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.app.demo.repo"})
@EntityScan(basePackages =
        {"org.app.demo.domain",
         "org.app.friflow.demo.process"
        })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .banner((environment, aClass,  printStream) ->
                        System.out.println(stringBanner()))
                .run();
    }
}
```

And SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebServiceAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private TokenProcessingFilter authTokenProcessingFilter;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/greeting")
                .hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

and lastly my application.properties file

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

security.basic.enabled=false
```

Whenever I submit the form I always receive this error. Was there an error in my configuration?

[image]

Comment: For starters how about configuring the simple fact that you are using form login? There is no trace of that in your configuration. Second the default URL is `/login` in newer spring security versions and not `/j_spring_security_check` anymore.

Comment: @M.Deinum How would I configure that I am using a form login? I wasn't aware of that j_spring_security_check

Comment: That is what `formLogin()` is for. If you don't configure that nothing is going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving,

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />">
```

you are changing the entire meaning of action attribute in your lines of code.